# Error inserting guid as primary key in object get set

Tags: c#, object, primary-key, guid

Trying to insert `GUID` as primary key within `object` `get` `set`. In the `set` section I checked if `value==null` to determine `insert` or `update`.

```
 public string Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Id;
        }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                this.Id = value == null ? this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D") : value;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `this.Id = value == null ? Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D") : value;` You dont need the 2nd `this.Id = `

Comment: You have a property ``Id`` and also a backing field ``Id``? It may be legal but I question the readability, you may want to rename the backing field. Furthermore your validation logic is (or may be, depending on your requirements) flawed, it checks for a null string but not whether a non-null string is valid for your use case.

Comment: @Loocid my bad. thanks

Comment: @dumetrulo noted, will make changes. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the get i'd say, it looks like you're returning `Id` when you are trying to access the value of `Id` so it will end up in an infinite loop and cause `System.StackOverflowException`

EDIT

You could also use the `??` operator to check for null values

Example

```
public string Id
{
    get
    {
        return this.Id;
    }
    set
    {
        try
        {
            this.Id = value ?? Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use the propery within the set or get... this will be an endless loop.
You use the property as the backing field.

Just define a backing-field and thats it.

```
private string id;
public string Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.id;
        }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                this.id = value == null ? Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D") : value;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, notice that like @Loocid  commented - while your code will work if you change to backing field, there's no need for the second `this.id =`